# How do I pipe the output of a file to a command?

Tags: linux, pipe

I'm trying to do something a bit like:

```
cat my_key.pub | send_key_to_server
```

It led me to try experiment as such:

```
cat my_key.pub | echo
```

which produced no output.

Finally I tried:

```
echo "hello" | echo
```

which also produced no output. I would have expected it to say "hello". Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
cat my_key.pub | xargs echo
```